# Зачем объявлять неясным вопрос, имеющий принятый ответ?

Tags: обсуждение, закрытие-вопросов

Собственно, периодически встречаю, что вопрос с принятым ответом помечен, как требующий правки в связи с неясностью. На мой взгляд, это бессмысленно, потому что автор не будет уточнять вопрос, если он уже получил ответ. К тому же, ответ с решением в таких случаях обычно уже содержит все требуемые уточнения.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Дополнение к [ответу](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1246/6) [@Tagir Valeev](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/183331/tagir-valeev).

- Если суть вопроса непонятна нескольким участникам, но он качественно оформлен и получил хороший развернутый ответ, я бы не стал голосовать за закрытие.
- Если вопрос оформлен некачественно, непонятен сообществу и получил настолько же непонятный некачественный ответ, который был отмечен принятым, то с большой вероятностью я проголосую за закрытие и поставлю голос против как вопроса, так и ответа.

Таким образом, хочу подчеркнуть, что самым важны для нас являются знания, которые могут помочь другим людям в будущем. Если мы видим, что ответ может быть полезен, но сам вопрос оставляет желать лучшего, то наиболее правильным действием будет улучшение вопроса. При этом не следует жалеть нетематические для сообщества вопросы или вопросы крайне низкого качества - мусор надо удалять.

Comment: не обоснован фактами тезис что мнение *отдельных* участников означает что все будущие посетители имеют такое же мнение. Например, я как правило не читаю дальше заголовка когда с поисковика прихожу и смотрю сразу на ответы и только если ответ сам по себе не ясен, то читаю тело вопроса -- для моей задачи, как правило подробности вопроса не имеют значения, то есть нужно учитывать *количество просмотров вопроса и отклик* (голоса анонимных пользователей (как дополнение к обычному голосованию)). Если "самым важным для нас являются знания", то нужно стараться использовать результаты наблюдений.

Answer (score 13):

StackOverflow нужен не для того, чтобы помочь конкретному человеку решить конкретную проблему, а в большей степени, чтобы сделать хороший FAQ на будущее. Поэтому каждый вопрос стоит рассматривать в этом контексте: а будет ли он полезен будущим читателям. Если автор неясно сформулировал свою мысль, но отвечающий проявил чудеса телепатии и правильно догадался, чего не хватает в вопросе, он, конечно, молодец, но что извлечёт из вопроса будущий посетитель? В принципе автору вопроса не должно быть жалко, что вопрос закрыли. Ответ он получил, проблема решена.

Однако лучше всего не закрывать вопрос, а редактировать. Обычно (на en.SO) если я правильно догадался, чего хочет автор и ответил на неясный вопрос так, что мой ответ оказался принятым, то я редактирую вопрос, добавляя в него все необходимые подробности, о которых я сам догадался. Это может сделать и любой случайный прохожий. Желательно, конечно, чтобы были полные права на редактирование (репа > 2000), а то ревьюверы обычно затупляют, думают, что человек отсебятины написал и отклоняют правку. В этом плане бета почему-то странно устроена: на en.SO сперва появляется право редактировать, а потом закрывать, что в этом контексте выглядит логично. А в бете наоборот.

Comment: в самом деле считаете, что вмире столько филантропов? (а сам ответ хороший)

Comment: "Поэтому каждый вопрос стоит рассматривать в этом контексте: а будет ли он полезен будущим читателям." - не только вопрос, но и ответ. Вопрос может быть задан кое-как, а ответ при этом полезен. Вроде даже знак есть за ответ с +10 на вопрос с -5 (или что-то такое - точно числа не помню, а смотреть лень). Закрывать его уже поздно. Хотя да, брать и редактировать - это может быть выходом, вопрос только, а кому это надо? Автору - скорее всего нет. А другие и не факт что вообще зайдут в вопрос с меткой on hold. Получается, надо не закрывать, а брать и править...

Comment: @Tagir Valeev очень интересный ответ, возможно где-нибудь на _мете_ есть тема связанная с редактированием вопросов?. Я уточню, у меня вопросы порой редактируют, в целом неплохие и полезные правки, но один раз, на мой взгляд вопрос был отредактирован весьма своевольно, человек многое изменил(даже и сам заголовок). Видя такие действия и ответы(как один выше), думаешь, что видимо здесь совсем не задумываются об авторстве ... завтра кому-то возможно что-то в вопросе покажется "требующим уточнения" и он начнет править, но возможно первоначальный автор не хотел таких уточнений и правок.

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov откатите правку и дело с концом. Причину отката напишите. Если человек продолжает упорно править (т.н. "война правок") жмите флажок "сообщить модератору" и там объясните, что происходит. Если за чередой правок авторство потерялось, можно объявить пост "общим" (community wiki), тогда автор светиться не будет.

Comment: @TagirValeev мне казалось, что если твое сообщение редактировали, то уведомление не получаешь об этом, или я не прав(возможно пропустил это)? Если прав, то предлагаю вам предыдущий свой комментарий удалить, как "вредный" совет,  т.к. логично что не будешь "мониторить" все свои сообщения и проверять не отредактировал ли их кто-нибудь.

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov вы не правы.

Comment: @TagirValeev Спасибо! Я проверил, действительно приходит уведомление, но не в "последние входящие сообщения" как я предполагал, а в личном кабинете, во вкладке `реакции`. Ваш комментарий мне, был полезен, я был не прав на счет этого.

Answer (score 2):

> К тому же, ответ с решением в таких случаях обычно уже содержит все требуемые уточнения.

вообще-то, закрывают вопрос (а не ответ), который как раз и «**не** содержит все **требуемые** уточнения».

Comment: Да, закрывают вопрос. Но вероятность его уточнения автором достаточно мала, поскольку он свой ответ уже получил. А ценность зависит ещё и от ответа, а не только от вопроса. Кстати, вероятно, гугл ищет по странице целиком, а значит и по ответам, так что интересующийся найдёт.