# Закрытие вопросов, на которые уже получен ответ

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, закрытие-вопросов, причины-закрытия

По следам моего [предыдущего вопроса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8565/176217) (кстати, до сих пор ещё остаётся без ответа) заметил, что обсуждаемый вопрос с несколькими *"UPD"* планируется к закрытию (на момент публикации я вижу 3 голоса). Возникает резонный вопрос:

Что мы получим, закрывая вопрос, на который ТС уже получил устроивший его ответ (галочка имеется)? Исключение шанса получить "более лучший" ответ? Профилактическое закрытие, дабы показать автору, что сообществу не понравилась такая схема обновления вопроса? Но ведь на нем более десятка плюсов - значит, вопрос интересен, и есть шанс, что те, кто выдал плюс, также предоставят и свой голос на переоткрытие.

В чём смысл закрывать подобные вопросы?

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1244/178988

Comment: @Qwertiy мог бы быть дубликатом, но мой, имхо, более широк (по закрытие в принципе по любой причине, хотя основан в первую очередь на причине "слишком общий"). Получается, надо бы редактировать то сообщение с кучей *UPD*, но ведь отдать голос на закрытие куда проще, чем редактировать.

Comment: Так я ж и не задубликатил)

Comment: @Qwertiy я и не упрекал :)

Answer (score 1):

Смысл в том, чтобы стимулировать автора вопроса вместо 14-го апдейта задать наконец отдельный вопрос, а не превращать и дальше существующий во всё менее вразумительный хлам. Мне доводилось несколько раз попадать на любителей бесконечных апдейтов. Доходило до того, что вопрос правился несколько дней подряд. Было даже, что не добавлением "UPD XX", а изменением первоначального текста вопроса. И если первые исправления были минимальными, то последние уже полностью переиначивали первоначальный вопрос. Это очень раздражает. Я стал бросать такие вопросы. И, если честно, больше никогда не отвечаю их авторам, опасаясь бесконечных правок.

Comment: Цель благая, но вряд ли это перевоспитает автора. На старые вопросы ответы есть, на новые кто-нибудь даст, пока они будут без UPD, а потом уже правками в режиме диалога снова вопрос превратится в хлам.